# any 3d drivers for ati fglrx which would support google earth and other 3d apps on chrome

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

i have installed many 3D apps on my ubuntu 14.04LTS desktop but none of them are supportive i have asked many questions regardind this previously but no answer was available 
i think it is just due to non availability of additional 3D drivers in my pc 
its a humble requwst if any one could hrlp me in solving this problem currenly i am using ATI Radeon 3000 graphics with AMD ATHLON 2 processor [3.4ghz]
i have used these 3d apps in the same computer but with windows 7 but now i have replaced windows 7 with ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit version 
i have BioDigital human 3d which is a great app to explore human bidy in detail but i cannot operate it in ubuntu 
is ubuntu really unsupportive to 3d graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think enabling WebGl in your browser would solve this issue for further details about how to enable it ou should refer this question
[how to enable WebGL in Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468349/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome)