# how to enable WebGL in Chrome

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, google-chrome, webgl

i am unable to visualise many 3d graphics of different applications [ex:-biodigital human 3d of chrome store] and many more 3d games and graphics i am current using Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 as my graphic card and do not know whether it is functioning or not in ubuntu but in windows 7 it works so can any body suggest stepwise settings or sequence of commands to get it fixed[image]

[image]
this screenshot shows a 3d app which is been supported in windows 7 installed through virtuaal box but the same thing i am unable to get it done in ubuntu

and this is shown when i type the command in terminal to know about my graphics card
[image]
[image]

*edit 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte)

Comment: Your card is an integrated Radeon HD3000 series. It is no longer supported by the proprietary AMD Catalyst drivers but it should work with the open source drivers. Most likely you do not get hardware support for WebGL because Chrome disables it by default. See [How To Enable WebGL In Chrome On Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu)

Comment: can you explain me how to get it done in a step wise manner

Comment: i have many times to install drivers from amd website but when i do it my computer goes blank and i have to reinstall ubuntu from disk can you help me to come out of this issue

Comment: You can not install the drivers from AMD web site on your computer. It is not possible because AMD do not support your graphics card any more. It is too old. You will have to use the open source drivers. Please read [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte) To enable WebGL for Chrome see [How To Enable WebGL In Chrome On Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu)

Comment: i have enabled webgl in chrome and its working superbly but i am getting too many problems to download fglrx drivers

Comment: my computer does not shows any additional drivers in the additional drivers option and everyone posts that to use the additional driver

Comment: You can not install the (proprietary, closed source) drivers from AMD web site on your computer. It is not possible because AMD do not support your graphics card any more. Your graphics card is too old. Your only option is to use the open source drivers.

Comment: how to use that open source driver @bain

Comment: You are already using it. It is installed by default in 14.04.

Comment: Check `glxinfo|grep 'OpenGL vendor'`

Comment: it shows some other thing which i have updated in my question

Comment: Try `glxinfo|grep -E 'OpenGL|direct'` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` - post the output to pastebin.com and link here. It is easier to copy and paste text than to take screenshots.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: It looks like you are using the open source drivers and have full accelerated 3D (`Direct rendering: Yes`). Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: i cannot get many application before but now after enabling webgl i am getting those but still some applications are unsupportive

Comment: Which applications? If some application does not work with the open source drivers then it is a bug. Report it at Launchpad or upstream with the xorg radeon project at http://wiki.x.org/wiki/radeon/

Comment: can you please see this question   http://askubuntu.com/questions/476078/ubuntu-14-04-gnome-crashed-after-installation

Comment: Did this bug not get fixed yesterday? You enabled acceleration in Chrome and it worked?

Comment: yes it was enabled and i can use it explicitly i am just requesting you to see this question and help me if you can thank you verymuch

Comment: Yes I was just wondering where all of the comments from yesterday went? Anyway, if you are happy with the answer to this question then please accept it so the question is closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes Google Chrome blocks 3D support in their browser in Linux due to known driver issues for example. However, there is a way to override this and force 3D support in Chrome.

To do this, navigate to `chrome://flags` in your browser. In there, search for the option `Ignore GPU blacklist` and **enable** it. After that you need to restart your browser to apply the changes.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Chrome 40.

Comment: Worked for Chrome 48.0.2564.82 (64-bit) on Linux Mint 17.3 / Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Works on Chrome 58 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 60 there is no **Ignore GPU blacklist**, but it is **Override software rendering list** now (the first line in `chrome://flags`)